# How to filter out built in user(Guest) and group(Admin) in Active Directory using C#?

Tags: c#, active-directory, subdomain, .net-framework-version

I am writing code to get users & groups from Active Directory, but I want to filter out built-in users & groups. built-in users eg: Guest Here is code snippet

```cs
subOUsearcher.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;

subOUsearcher.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person))";

var objSearchResults = subOUsearcher.FindAll();
```

Answer (score 0):

Really, you just need to look for an attribute that is specific to built-in accounts. I took a look myself (using the "Attribute Editor" tab in AD Users and Computers), and I found the [`isCriticalSystemObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-iscriticalsystemobject) attribute, which you can use in your filter like this:

```
subOUsearcher.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person)(!isCriticalSystemObject=TRUE))";
```